# Firefox 88 error after clicking an external link when already open

Tags: firefox

When clicking an external link (say from Thunderbird) the link fails to open and the following error message presented.

"Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile."

Works fine if Chrome is the default browser and works OK with Firefox 88 on an Android phone.

Current OS is Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Firefox not properly closing down.It can be due to a range of issues such as custom theming, extensions, graphics acceleration. See the [support page of Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems) for troubleshooting.

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue. I used to routinely run commands like `firefox xkcd.com` from the terminal, to load the website in a new tab in my existing firefox session. Now, every time I run this command I get the "Firefox is already running" popup error. 

Still working on finding a solution/workaround. Also an explanation of what changed in latest versions of Firefox and/or ubuntu 20.04.3 that led to this...